# Split a string and convert to custom type

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have string which I wanted to to split by character `x` and then wanted to convert resultant string array to user defined type. for example I have string `1800x1200` and wanted to convert into my type called `Layout` as below:

```
public class Layout
{
    public Double LongSide { get; set; }
    public Double ShortSide { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You think it a bit wrong, this is called *parsing*. Simply provide `Parse(string)` method of your type `Layout`. And there you probably can create an instance, split string, parse to int, initialize fields/properties and return that instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a lambda expression or a LINQ query for something like that, You can do:

```
string str = "1800x1200";
string[] array = str.Split('x');
Layout layout = new Layout()
{
    LongSide = double.Parse(array[0]),
    ShortSide = double.Parse(array[1])
};
```

*Make sure to check for size of the returned array from Split, and also consider using `double.TryParse` if your string can contain non numeric values.*

LINQ can be useful if you are dealing with a collection of string values, instead of a single string like:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>
{
   "1800x1200",
   "1600x1000",
   "1400x800",
   "1200x600",
};

List<Layout> layoutList 
    = list.Select(r => r.Split('x'))
           .Select(r => new Layout
                    {
                        LongSide = double.Parse(r[0]),
                        ShortSide = double.Parse(r[1])
                    })
            .ToList();
```

With a collection of string you can use LINQ to get a collection of your custom object.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already have implemented this approach but I was looking for one liner solution for this.

Comment: @Sameer, don't over complicate things. LINQ is useful if you are working with a collection. If you are only going to deal with a single item, you don't need LINQ.

Comment: @Sameer, here is the one liner, see just how bad it is to read `Layout layout = new[] { "1800x1200" }.Select(r => r.Split('x')).Select(r => new Layout { LongSide = double.Parse(r[0]), ShortSide = double.Parse(r[1]) }).First();`

Comment: Just make it an extension, then you can do something like

someString.GetLSRes();  and have it return an object of type Layout or null.

Comment: I have created class as below : `public class Layout
    {
        public double LongSide { get; set; }
        public double ShortSide { get; set; }

        public Layout(string layoutString)
        {
            string[] dimensions = layoutString.Split('x');
            this.LongSide = double.Parse(dimensions[0]);
            this.ShortSide = double.Parse(dimensions[1]);
        }
    }` and calling the constructor like `Layout areaLayout = new Layout("1800X1200");`. I feel this is simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

Using a little Lambda (but not much!):

```
string input = "1800x1200";

var sizes = input
    .Split('x')
    .ToList()
    .Select(d => double.Parse(d));

Layout layout = new Layout
{
    LongSide = sizes.First(),
    ShortSide = sizes.Last()
};
```

Comment: Making it a bit shorter `var sizes = input.Split('x').Select(double.Parse);`

Answer (score 1):

I have created class as below:

> `public class Layout
>       {
>           public double LongSide { get; set; }
>           public double ShortSide { get; set; }
>           public Layout(string layoutString)
>           {
>               string[] dimensions = layoutString.Split('x');
>               this.LongSide = double.Parse(dimensions[0]);
>               this.ShortSide = double.Parse(dimensions[1]);
>           }
>       }`

and calling it as: `Layout areaLayout = new Layout("1800x1200");`

I feel this is the simplest way to do this. Please provide your comments.

Comment: I like it. Moving that into the constructor avoids repeating linq code.

Answer (score 0):

One liner solution?

```
var layout = input
    .Split('x')
    .Select(double.Parse)
    .GroupBy(x => 0)
    .Select(g => new Layout { LongSide = g.ElementAt(0), ShortSide = g.ElementAt(1) })
    .Single();
```